# Simple push array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am ashamed to ask that but it is making me crazy.

I try to push an array into another array as follow:

```
var person = {"bla":"46","bla2":"46","bla3":"46"};
var test = {"bla4":"46","bla5":"46"};
person.push(test);
```

Well it is not working and I don't see why.
Can someone see what I am doing wrong and maybe have the good way to proceed ?

thanks

Comment: Those are not arrays, but objects.

Comment: Thank you. Still a long way to learn even the basics ...